# dragging a link to an input and append its text to it

Tags: javascript, html, input, hyperlink

if you dragg any hyperlink `<a href="go.php">` to an imput (for example a search input), the href attribute is append to the input's content, `<input type="text" value="http://domain.com/go.php" />`

Is there a way to append the title attribute instead, or the `innerHtml`?

I ask this because I want to avoid the use of jQuery UI's draggable extension.

Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: I believe this behavior is a browser feature and does not exist in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you dragg any hyperlink  to an imput (for example
>   a search input), the href attribute is append to the input's content,

I think you mean that the value of the input is set to the href of the link. Anyway, it isn't in IE 8.

There are other drag and drop libraries with much less overhead than jQuery + jQueryUI, I suspect that many of them will allow you to do what you want when one element is dragged to another. e.g. [myLibrary](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib-doc0.html) has an [attachdrag](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib-doc.asp#attachdrag) function where you can specify what happens when an element is dropped.

So just check the dropped element's tagname and if it's an A, look for the href to check if it's a link then do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As James said, this is indeed a browser feature, and it doesn't seem that JavaScript can intercept it; that is, no event fires when you release your mouse over an input field if you're dragging an element into it. If you're set on not using draggable, one alternative would be to put masks over your input elements whenever the mouse goes down on a link, store their positions, then query those positions when the mouse goes back up to determine which input field was targeted.